# Convert XML to minimal branches to import into SQL Server with SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xslt, ssis

I have a complex XML file that I am trying to import into SQL Server using SQL Server Data Tools. The issue is that there are many nested elements. The SSIS XML Source identifies each collection of children elements as their own table.

For example, I have the following (simplified) XML and XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrafficReport>
    <TrafficElement>
        <counts>
            <vehicles>
                <vehiclesElement>
                    <vehicleType>car</vehicleType>
                    <vehicleCount>15</vehicleCount>
                </vehiclesElement>
                <vehiclesElement>
                    <vehicleType>truck</vehicleType>
                    <vehicleCount>5</vehicleCount>
                </vehiclesElement>
            </vehicles>
            <pedestrian>4</pedestrian>
        </counts>
        <description>
            <type>Manual</type>
        </description>
    </TrafficElement>
</TrafficReport>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="Vehicle">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="vehicleType" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="vehicleCount" type="xs:short"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TrafficCounts">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="vehicles">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="vehiclesElement" type="Vehicle"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pedestrian" type="xs:short"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TrafficType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Traffic">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="counts" type="TrafficCounts"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="TrafficType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="TrafficReport">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="TrafficElement" type="Traffic"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Using the above XML and XSD, I have the following output tables from SSIS:
[image: SSIS options for original XML (7 tables)]

My problem with how SSIS creates the tables is that there are so many intermediate tables linking a single child element to the parent element.

My current solution for this is to create an XSL file that transforms the source data into the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TrafficReport>
    <TrafficElement>
        <vehiclesElement>
            <vehicleType>car</vehicleType>
            <vehicleCount>15</vehicleCount>
        </vehiclesElement>
        <vehiclesElement>
            <vehicleType>truck</vehicleType>
            <vehicleCount>5</vehicleCount>
        </vehiclesElement>
        <pedestrian>4</pedestrian>
        <type>Manual</type>
    </TrafficElement>
</TrafficReport>
```

Here is the XSL file I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="TrafficReport">
        <TrafficReport>
            <xsl:for-each select="TrafficElement">
                <TrafficElement>
                    <xsl:for-each select="counts/vehicles/vehiclesElement">
                        <vehiclesElement>
                            <vehicleType><xsl:value-of select="vehicleType" /></vehicleType>
                            <vehicleCount><xsl:value-of select="vehicleCount" /></vehicleCount>
                        </vehiclesElement>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <pedestrian><xsl:value-of select="counts/pedestrian" /></pedestrian>
                    <type><xsl:value-of select="description/type" /></type>
                </TrafficElement>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TrafficReport>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the new XML, SSIS wants to create the following tables which are much easier to work with:
[image: SSIS Options for 2nd tables (only 2 tables)]

My solution is to pull any children elements to their parent elements, as long as it is a 1:1 relationship. The problem is that creating the XSL file is time consuming (over 750 elements) and I need to do this for multiple files.

1. Is there an automated way to compress XML to the minimum elements like I am doing manually? (Preferably within SSDT.)
2. Am I using the XML Source data task incorrectly with the first XML? When trying with the actual data, SSDT identifies over 100 output tables.
3. Any general suggestions on importing complex XML into SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have number of XML files, it's seems you need to use script component to process your XML files, where you can put your logic to extract required data from XML. Also you can [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb943906.aspx) to process your files which is quite faster.